# How can I use output arguments in querystring as input?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

UPDATE: I have customized the Marble chaincode to my own purpose, where I want to track products through a production system. So at each manufacturing operation a new transaction would be recorded where an outgoingID from the previous operation would become an ingoingID to this station. Now I can query by an outgoingID and see all ingoingID which has become this outgoingID. But this is only for one operation. So to link these different ID together I want to use the resulting ID from a query as input to a new query.

I'm trying to access arguments from the output querystring in the [Build Your First network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html).

The code looks like this:

```
func (t *SimpleChaincode) queryMarbles(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {

    //   0
    // "queryString"
    if len(args) < 1 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1")
    }

    queryString := args[0]

    queryResults, err := getQueryResultForQueryString(stub, queryString)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }
    return shim.Success(queryResults)
}
```

```
func getQueryResultForQueryString(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, queryString string) ([]byte, error) {

    fmt.Printf("- getQueryResultForQueryString queryString:\n%s\n", queryString)

    resultsIterator, err := stub.GetQueryResult(queryString)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resultsIterator.Close()

    buffer, err := constructQueryResponseFromIterator(resultsIterator)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("- getQueryResultForQueryString queryResult:\n%s\n", buffer.String())

    return buffer.Bytes(), nil
}
```

At gives the following output:

```
Query Result: [{"Key":"marble1", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}}]
```

If I wanted to use "tom" (owner) as an input to a new query, how could I instead of return the query result use the output as input arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I find it unclear what you mean by

> instead of return the query result use the output as input arguments

There's the [queryMarblesByOwner chaincode function](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/marbles02/go/marbles_chaincode.go#L20-L22), but only if using couchdb.

`peer chaincode query -C myc1 -n marbles -c '{"Args":["queryMarblesByOwner","tom"]}'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have customized the Marble chaincode to my own purpose, where I want to track products through a production system. So at each manufacturing operation a new transaction would be recorded where an outgoingID from the previous operation would become an ingoingID to this station. Now I can query by an outgoingID and see all ingoingID which has become this outgoingID. But this is only for one operation. So to link these different ID together I want to use the resulting ID from a query as input to a new query. Is this more clear?